# How to remove the bottom line of UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Whenever I create a tableView,there will be a line at the bottom of the last cell,is there a method to remove it?I don't use the Xib or Storyboard,so please show me the code.Thank you very much!

Sorry I didn't describe the situation clearly,here is the Screenshot,I have two sections in this tableview,and there is a line at the bottom of the last cell

[image: Here is screenshot]

Comment: how many sections?

Comment: I do not see any extra line in the screenshot. What are you talking about ?

Answer (score 4):

The solution is really easy if you just take a custom cell.

Firstly drag and drop a cell in your TableView and then select the TableView to make it's separator as None like-

[image]

Then Assign the UITableViewCell's class top the custom one.

[image]

In the TableViewCell in storyboard, take your required Objects like Lables, images or whatever you need. Now, make sure you take a UIView of 1 px at the bottom of the cell. Connect the outlets and add the required constrains.

[image]

Your Custom Class may look like -

CustomTableViewCell.h file-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *customTextLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *separatorView;

@end
```

Now in the View Controller, just show or hide the separator at the bottom row of your section.

So, your Datasource methods may look like-

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 2;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section == 0){
        return 2;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"sampleCell"];

    if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1){
        cell.separatorView.hidden = YES;
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0){
        cell.separatorView.hidden = YES;
    }
    else{
        cell.separatorView.hidden = NO;
    }
    cell.customTextLabel.text = @"Test"; //put whatever you want
    return cell;
}
```

You should get a outlook like-

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For removing last line i.e last separator of tableview, you have to use below code in UIViewDidload

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

OR if you want to remove particular cell separator use inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleDefault;

    if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1)
    { 
       tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried that, but it didn't work.The line is still there.

Comment: As per your screenshot, you have to take condition for last row. And inside that condition you have to use this tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewSeparatorStyleNone;

Comment: I did what you said  ,here is my code in the   `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method  `if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1) {
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    }` ,but the result is that every cell has been removed the bottomline.I don't know whether this separatorStyle property can be used like this.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the line below the cell use the following:

```
// set properties tableView
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 0):

You can design your own custom footer for `UITableView`
But i don't think by default tableView show any footer.
As Your question is unclear and you haven't provide any screenshot or anything else.
Create your custom view with your desired colour contents and then just assign it to your tableView.

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = customFooterView;
```

Or Maybe you want to hide/remove the tableView `LineSeparator`
There are two most easy approaches to do this.
Either assign a clear colour to separator or assign none to separator.

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewSeparatorStyleNone;
```

or

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```