# Hide border Top and Bottom in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Make the Style of UITableView Grouped.
Can I erase the top and bottom lines?

I marked it with a blue marker in the image.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouped UITableview remove outer separator line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006311/grouped-uitableview-remove-outer-separator-line)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the bottom line of UITableView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555529/how-to-remove-the-bottom-line-of-uitableview-in-ios)

Comment: thank you everyone.
Apparently it seems difficult in my situation.
The idea of Mr. Xavier was the closest way to solve it.
However, in my case, it was impossible to realize because Section's background is white.
I will research a little more.